# AppleScript - Delete first 10 lines of string

Tags: string, applescript

I want to write an **AppleScript** that will delete the first 10 lines of a string.

```
set text to "Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
Line 8
Line 9
Line 10
Line 11
Line 12
Line 13"
```

So the result of variable text would be:

```
Line 11
Line 12
Line 13
```

Thanks.

**Editor's note:** The question's massive input/output affected readability. Deleting the first 10 will suffice. You should be able to extrapolate the solution to 30 lines.

Comment: Show your approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
   sed '1,10d'
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.